# Error : "Out of Memory ", when converting .jls image to byte[] array

Tags: c#, image, memory, image-conversion

I have this function which converts an Image to Byte array.

```
  public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

This is my code for calling the function.

```
  private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       inputPath=textbox1.text;

        try
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = Image.FromFile(inputPath);
           byte[] str= imageToByteArray(img);
         }


     catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

When I run the program, or when the event is triggered, it throws an exception which says "Out of Memory" - Why is this happening?

I'm using this function to decode .jls images(images compressed using the JPEG-LS algorithm). So this clearly means the file is not supported, right? Would you know any other alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd.aspx):

> If the file does not have a valid image format or if GDI+ does not
>   support the pixel format of the file, this method throws an
>   OutOfMemoryException exception.

Further more:

> The Image class does not support alpha transparency in bitmaps. To
>   enable alpha transparency, use PNG images with 32 bits per pixel.

More information on supported formats can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at62haz6.aspx).

Comment: +1 for the comment, but doesn't that sound strange? By that I mean reporting an OOM Exception when that isn't the actual cause. I would have thought something like InvalidOperationException or something similar would have been more appropriate.

Comment: I'm using this  function to decode .jls images(images compressed using the JPEG-LS algorithm). So this clearly means the file is not supported, right? Would you know any other alternatives?

Comment: @MrMoose: Since it's a GDI+ wrapper the exception is coming from GDI+. Or rather the Error Code. GDI+ only has about 22 Error Codes IIRC and the OOM error code can mean many things. Sometimes it means OOM sometimes it means something else.

Comment: @Sani Huttunun : Yes, I'm trying to implement CharLS in C#, apparently they don't provide decompression examples.

Answer (score 1):

try this for Image to byte[]:

```
 byte[] str = File.ReadAllBytes("InputImagePath");

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
       inputPath=textbox1.text;  

        try  
        {  
          byte[] str= File.ReadAllBytes("inputPath");
        }  


     catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of Memory exception is very self-explaining.

You could try the following

- Try different size of image, and observe which size range the system starts getting out of memory exception
- Try dispose your `MemoryStream`

**Example**

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
    {
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```